redash docker compose build issue
ss of error 
While setting up redash throwing this dependency error , But this docker file present in official repo
dockerfile from redash repo 
While setting up redash in vm (Linux) I faced this issue. How can I solve , I even tried with node:18.1 but its not working as expected

Did you check that your Docker uses Node version 18 only? Because it needs to be Node version 18.
